# GAE: Serve CSS file dynamically with correct mime type

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am trying to bundle all my CSS files into one in a dynamic way and serve that through my Google app engine. This works if I go to the URL `/app.css` in the browser:

```
- url: /app.css
  script: _corecss.php
```

When I plug this into my web page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My Test App</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
...
```

The console shows an error and no style is applied

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

When I look in the chrome developer tools, I can see content-length being set, but there is no response data - no idea why, at a guess its something that's realizing I'm not sending CSS to dumps the lot. I do exactly the same thing for my JavaScript and it seems to load fine with the content-type set as text/html.

I googled the error and found that I could set the mime types in the app.yaml:

```
- url: /app.css
  mime_type: 'text/css'
  script: _corecss.php
```

But this did not work. Further googling suggested that the `mime-type` directive can only be done on static stuff.

More googleing and I found I should be able to set the headers:

```
- url: /app.css
  script: _corecss.php
  http_headers:
  Content-Type: text/css
```

This did not work either, and there was mixed info on whether content-type was allowed.

I used to regenerate files on the page load and store them if there were changes, but GAE has stopped access to the file system locally so I can't do this any more.

Any ideas how I can generate my CSS file and serve it so that my application does not complain?

Thanks

Comment: Found another google may get to it eventually thread: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1050

Answer (score 0):

The answer was painfully simple. In the backend PHP script set the Content-type header:

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

All working now. Man that was hard to figure, so I thought I'd answer this question (rather than delete it) in case someone else needs it.